# How do you check if a PowerShell variable is an ordered hashtable?

Tags: powershell, variables, hashtable

In PowerShell, how do you check if a variable is a hashtable, whether it be ordered or not?

In the first instance, I was testing if an ordered hashtable was of type `Hashtable`, but it seems that it is not.

Following this, I checked the variable type using `GetType()`. This seems to show that ordered hashtables are of type `OrderedDictionary`.

Finally, I tested if an ordered hashtable was of type `OrderedDictionary`, but this results in an error.

I assume that there must be a way to do this?

#### Checking for `Hashtable` only

```
$standard = @{}
$ordered = [ordered]@{}

if ($standard -is [Hashtable]) { Write-Output "True" } else { Write-Output "False" }
if ($ordered -is [Hashtable]) { Write-Output "True" } else { Write-Output "False" }
```

> True
>   False

#### Getting the type of variable for normal and ordered hashtables

Looking at the type of the variables, I can see that `$ordered` seems to be a different type called `OrderedDictionary`.

```
$standard = @{}
$ordered = [ordered]@{}

Write-Output $standard.GetType()
Write-Output $ordered.GetType()



IsPublic IsSerial Name              BaseType  
-------- -------- ----              --------  
True     True     Hashtable         System.Object  
True     True     OrderedDictionary System.Object
```

#### Checking for `Hashtable` or `OrderedDictionary`

However, when I check if a variable is of type `OrderedDictionary`, I'm presented with an error stating that the type cannot be found.

```
$standard = @{}
$ordered = [ordered]@{}

if (($standard -is [Hashtable]) -or ($standard -is [OrderedDictionary])) { Write-Output "True" } else { Write-Output "False" }
if (($ordered -is [Hashtable]) -or ($ordered -is [OrderedDictionary])) { Write-Output "True" } else { Write-Output "False" }
```

> True
>   Unable to find type [OrderedDictionary].

Comment: You'll need to be explicit: `[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]`. The PowerShell console offers completion for this if you just type `[OrderedDictionary]` and hit Tab inside the brackets. Because `System` is optional, you can shorten this slightly to `[Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]`, but no shorter than that. (At least, I know of no way to shorten that further; `Hashtable` appears to get special treatment.)

Comment: Incidentally, rather than testing for either of these concrete types explicitly, testing for `-is [System.Collections.IDictionary]` is probably a better idea, as it covers both of them plus anything else you can access in the same way.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thank you very much, that worked. I've also found that if I add a `using namespace System.Collections.Specialized` to the top of my script, I can indeed shorten it's usage to simply `[OrderedDictionary]`.

Comment: `using namespace` was added in PowerShell 5. Nice, I didn't know about it. :-)

Comment: Each time I have question about classes, I use get-Member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been point out in the comments, the full namespace-qualified type name is:

```
[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]
```

If you want to accept *both* types, as a parameter argument in a function for example, use their common interface `IDictionary`:

```
function Test-IsOrdered
{
  param(
    [System.Collections.IDictionary]
    $Dictionary
  )

  $Dictionary -is [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]
}
```

`Test-IsOrdered` will now accept *any* dictionary type including a regular `[hashtable]`: `Test-IsOrdered @{}`, but only `Test-IsOrdered ([ordered]@{})` will return `$true`

Answer (score 2):

As stated in above comments, you can check for `System.Collections.IDictionary` interface which is implemented by both classes to check if a variable is a hashtable in general:

```
> $standard -is [System.Collections.IDictionary]
True
> $ordered -is [System.Collections.IDictionary]
True
```

The `OrderedDictionary` is defined in [System.Collections.Specialized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=netframework-4.8), therefore you've to check against:

```
> $ordered -is [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]
True
> $standard -is [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Il use `Get-Member` to get the final type.

```
($ordered | Get-Member)[0].TypeName
```

gives : *System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary*